# Static short reference yields an error in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

Here's the whole source:

```
#include <iostream>
void recursion(static short &di);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    short pi = 1;
    for(pi; pi > 0; pi++)
    {
        cout << "Hi, pi!" << "\n";
        recursion(pi);
    }
}
void recursion(static short &di)
{
    di++;
    if(di < 20)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << di << "\n";    
    }
}
```

For some reason it works fine when the 16-bit container isn't static, but I want it to be static, and it gives the following error:

> main.cpp:2:29: error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations
>    void recursion(static short di);
>                                ^
>   main.cpp:2:29: error: storage class specified for parameter 'di'
>   main.cpp:14:29: error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations
>    void recursion(static short di)
>                                ^
>   main.cpp:14:29: error: storage class specified for parameter 'di'

Comment: I'm absolutely baffled as to what you thought a static parameter would do

Comment: Read and think - that error message is quite trivial!

Answer (score 8):

You can't specify a `static` storage duration for function parameters.

You can still pass a reference to a `static` variable to a function, and the reference will still refer to a `static` variable.

For example:

```
int main()
{
   static short pi = 1;
// ^^^^^^
   for(pi; pi > 0; pi++)
   {
   cout << "Hi, pi!" << "\n";
   recursion(pi);
   }
// ...
}

void recursion(short &di)
{
// ...
}
```

But in your case making `pi` a `static` seems rather pointless.

---

You might not fully understand what a `static` storage duration means, so I'll take the liberty to explain.

Normally you declare variable without the `static` qualifier like this:

```
void foo()
{
  int myValue = 42;
}
```

A variable declared like this has *automatic* storage duration; meaning when it "goes out of scope", the object is destroyed.  If you were to call `foo()` 100 times:

```
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    foo();
}
```

...then `myValue` would be re-initialized 100 times.  Normally this is exactly what you want.

Sometimes you want a variable to outlive the scope in which it's declared.  To accomplish this, you give it *static* storage duration, using the `static` keyword:

```
void foo()
{
  static int myValue = 42;
}
```

A variable declared this way will be initialized exactly *once*, before it's first usage, and will continue to live even after its gone out of scope.  It will retain it's value until it's been reassigned, until the program ends.

---

Your code:

```
int main()
{
    short pi = 1;
    for(pi; pi > 0; pi++)
    {
        cout << "Hi, pi!" << "\n";
        recursion(pi);
    }
}
```

establishes the `pi` variable, and then calls `recursion` a number of times.  Here `pi` does *not* need static storage duration, because it will never go out of scope during the loop where you call `recursion`.  All you have to do is pass a reference to `pi` to `recursion`, and it will behave as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit; you cannot have a `static` qualifier for a formal argument; you need to declare

```
  void recursion(short &di);
```

and later to define

```
  void recursion(short &di) {
    di++;
    if(di < 20)
      return;
    else
      cout << di << "\n";    
  }
```